# New JSON call on Google pie chart

Tags: php, javascript, google-visualization

On my little tool I am working on a dashboard using Google charts. I managed to populate the different graphs using php and mysql. 
When the page is loaded I am retrieving YTD (respectively all data) but now I want to give the possiblity to hit a button and to only show data based on the current month or week. Now I am having trouble to update the existing pie chart with the new value and I have no idea how to do this. So any help would be highly appreciate it.

The code initializing my pie chart

```
<script type="text/javascript">             // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.             google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.           google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                var json = $.ajax({

                    url: 'data2.php', // make this url point to the data file
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false
                }).responseText;


                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
                var options = {
                    chartArea: {left:0, height:"90%", width:"100%"}


                };
                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                //do not forget to check ur div ID

             var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));

                chart.draw(data, options);



            }       </script>
```

The HTML shows below the pie chart three buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button id="datebutton0" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="updateButton(0);">YTD</button>
<button id="datebutton1" class="btn" onClick="updateButton(1);" title="Woche">Month</button>
<button id="datebutton2" class="btn" onClick="updateButton(2);" title="Monat">Week</button>

</div>
```

Now I want to be able to re-calculate the data coming from a mysql statement and to update the pie chart. So what would I do next? Shall I create an ajax sending the value to the data2.php which is then sending the new data to the pie chart and how would it get updated?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: This can be closed I found a good way.

Comment: So.. What is the good way ? If you post a question and you know the answer you can post the answer.